# "6 Dess" on older German postcards

Tags: abbreviation

On older German postcards, a few times I've seen "6 Dess" or "6 Des" along with the publisher, series, etc.  What does that mean ?  Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us an example?

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a sorting marker introduced by the publisher - They apparently subdivided their postcards into *Serien* and *Dessins* (from French), i.e. "series" and "designs" (subjects) in order to be able to more easily address a single card when ordered. So, it's basically a kind of order number.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a punctuation after the 6 then?

Comment: @Beta : if it's for internal use - why? They can make their own rules ...

Comment: I have six different postcards from the same series (serie). 6 Dess would then mean there are 6 cards to the set, oui?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with the text "Dessin 2":
[image: Postcard]